# Most pythonic way to assign several values based on single input

Tags: python, database, class

I need to assign several variables based on a single user input.  My code has organically evolved into the following structure, and I'd like to upgrade to something more pythonic.

```
def build_simulation(type='running'):
  var1 = {'running': 1,       'starting': 2,       'stopping': 3}
  var2 = {'running': math.pi, 'starting': 7/9,     'stopping': 1e-6}
  varN = {'running': 'this',  'starting': 'is an', 'stopping': 'example'}

  return other_function(var1[type])+var2[type], text+varN[type]
```

My simulation could end up having *several* types, and other users may want to add their own types (or variables) later on.  Can anyone suggest a highly pythonic way to set this up for posterity?

So far I have considered building a giant matrix (numpy?  pandas?), or since I've recently discovered the joy of OOP, possibly doing something clever with a Class.

Edit: clarification was requested on the project.  I am generating input decks for an iterative fortran code, where my main() would have the form:

```
build sim1 from scratch, type='startup'
run sim1
build sim2 from sim1 results, type='running'
run sim2
build sim3 from sim2 results, type='shutdown'
run sim3
build sim4 from sim3 results, type='startup'
run sim4
build sim5 from sim4 results, type='Accident Scenario 1'
```

So the goal is to put all the 'type' information in one place so that if other users want to add more, it's all in one spot in the code and it's easy to make the addition.  I also want to use a general method that will make it easy to add additional functionality later as the simulation becomes more complex.

Comment: A class with `running`, `starting`, and `stopping` as member variables makes sense to me over a dictionary

Comment: At first I agreed with your premise, but now that I look at it, I'm not sure what the problem is...

Comment: It might be worth cross-slicing this; have `RunningSim`, `StartingSim`, `StoppingSim` each with their own `var1`, `var2` ... `varN`. Then a new type would be a new subclass of `Simulation`, ie `class PausedSim(Simulation):`. Can you tell us a bit more about the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Similar to what cricket_007 said, you could use a `namedtuple` as a light weight solution where you would have a dictionary where each "key" maps to a namedtuple instance (or another dictionary) for each type.

Comment: It's not clear what actual problem you are trying to solve here, so it's hard to tell which would be more pythonic. What I think is that you might want to aim for more maintainable rather and less dependent on particular input vector (in the sense: modifying the code depending on changing the input data). Given such constraints I can only guess that a truth table where var1, var2 .. varN would be columns might be the best option. Again, since I do not know the problem TB solved that's just speculation.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Provided some clarification on the actual project.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You would create a separate function for each scenario (keeping related data together). The cost would be either making your scenario parameters global (shown here), or perhaps putting them into a dictionary or making them properties of a simple object:

```
def _build_sim_running():
    global var1, var2, ... varN
    var1 = 1
    var2 = math.pi
    # ...
    varN = 'this'

def _build_sim_starting():
    global var1, var2, ... varN
    var1 = 2
    var2 = 7.0/9
    # ...
    varN = 'is an'

def _build_sim_stopping():
   global var1, var2, ... varN
   var1 = 3
   var2 = 1e-6
   # ...
   varN = 'example'

Simulation_builder = {
    'startup': _build_sim_starting,
    'shutdown': _build_sim_shutdown,
    'running': _build_sim_running,
}

def build_simulation(type='running'):
    fn = Simulation_builder[type]
    fn()
```